# how can i test the true positves of a trained network keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a trained model and want to know the fairness of this model based on the true positive rate for each sensitive group. Data will already be preprocessed and have a sensitive group isolated.

how can I return the true positive rate?

```
def test_fairness(data, mymodel):
    y = data["Income binary"]
    x = data.drop(["Income binary"], axis=1)
    _, accuracy = mymodel.evaluate(x=x , y=y)
    return accuracy
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into TensorFlow and Keras documentation. They have very extensive guides to do almost anything.

This might help:

- [TensorFlow docs | TruePositive](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/TruePositives)
- [Keras docs | TruePositive](https://keras.io/api/metrics/classification_metrics/#truepositives-class)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only found examples of that method being used during training.

Comment: You can use the same metric constructor to call on true labels, and predicted labels which should give you the result.